# Calling child method from parent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I've a JavaScript class, and I'd like to override a parent method by creating a child class. However, I am struggling to work out how to call the child method from the context of the parent.

Here's a trimmed-down version of my parent:

```
// "rules" is a global hash

function ForumFilter() {
    this.scanText = function(title, body) {
        // Save 'this' context, as each() overwrites it
        var that = this;
        // This is jQuery each()
        $.each(rules, function(ruleName, rule) {
            // rule.search is a regex
            var match = rule.search.test(body);
            if (match)
            {
                that.isPassed = false;
                // ** I'd like to call a child method here,
                // ** but it only calls the method in this class
                that.setRuleFailed(ruleName);
            }
        });
    }

    this.setRuleFailed = function(ruleName) {
        this.failedRules.push(ruleName);
    }
}
```

Here's my attempt at the child:

```
ForumFilterTest.prototype = new ForumFilter();
ForumFilterTest.prototype.setRuleFailed = function(ruleName) {
    // Call parent
    ForumFilter.setRuleFailed(ruleName);
    // Record that this one has triggered
    this.triggered.push(ruleName);
}
```

Here's my calling my parent method from a child instance:

```
var scanner = new ForumFilterTest();
scanner.scanText("Hello", "Hello");
```

So, in `scanText` (which only exists in the parent) it may call `setRuleFailed`, which should call the version in `ForumFilterTest`, which in turn calls the class it overrides. Thus, as its name implies, I am trying to add a behaviour to the parent for testing purposes, so of course I want the parent method to be used if `ForumFilter` is instantiated on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After understanding your problem better, here's my actual proposed changes.  Specifically, you need to move your `ForumFilter` methods to its `prototype`.  That will allow `ForumFilterTest` methods to explicitly reference `ForumFilter` methods.

**Step 1:** Move `ForumFilter` methods to its `prototype`.

```
function ForumFilter() {}
ForumFilter.prototype.scanText = function(title, body) {
    // Save 'this' context, as each() overwrites it
    var that = this;
    // This is jQuery each()
    $.each(rules, function(ruleName, rule) {
        // rule.search is a regex
        var match = rule.search.test(body);
        if (match)
        {
            that.isPassed = false;
            // ** I'd like to call a child method here,
            // ** but it only calls the method in this class
            that.setRuleFailed(ruleName);
        }
    });
};
ForumFilter.prototype.setRuleFailed = function(ruleName) {
    this.failedRules.push(ruleName);
};
```

**Step 2:** Explicitly reference `ForumFilter` "parent" method when needed:

```
// "child class" implementation
function ForumFilterTest() {}
ForumFilterTest.prototype = new ForumFilter();
ForumFilterTest.prototype.setRuleFailed = function(ruleName) {
    // Call parent
    ForumFilter.prototype.setRuleFailed.call(this, ruleName);
    // Record that this one has triggered
    this.triggered.push(ruleName);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciate the jsFiddle example. It's nearly what I am aiming for, however I want the child to be able to call the parent, as [per this](http://jsfiddle.net/Tsmgg/2/). Thus, it adds to the parent rather than replaces it.

Comment: Ahh, you'll need to move the parent methods to the prototype so that "overridden" methods can still be explicitly invoked by child classes.  See this: http://jsfiddle.net/Tsmgg/3/

Comment: Superb, many thanks! That's exactly what I'm after, and I've modified my own use case successfully. So, even though the parent methods existed before, they were invisible to the child?

Comment: Correct. Your `ForumFilter` methods were previously set in the constructor and were therefore *instance* level. This meant that once you ran `ForumFilterTest.prototype = new ForumFilter()`, these methods were now directly on the `ForumFilterTest`'s prototype, rather than further up the prototype chain.  That resulted in the parent `setRuleFailed` method being completely overridden by the `ForumFilterTest.prototype.setRuleFailed = function() {...}` call, since that was where the *parent* `setRuleFailed` implementation was stored as well.